# How to configure port number for OwnCloud snap install?

Tags: snap, owncloud-server

I've tried using snap to install OwnCloud (I also tried NextCloud), and it works really well, except that it runs on port 80.

Using port 80 would be fine if it were the only thing on the server, but it's not, and anyway I want to put a https server in front of it (I use nginx, but that shouldn't be relevant here).

How can I configure the snap to use a different port and only accept connections from localhost?

I want to use the snap for both the convenience and the confinement. I'm currently achieving the same thing with Docker, but doing upgrades is clunky and I'd like to at least try the new way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE 2018**: this is now possible [via "snap set"](https://github.com/nextcloud/nextcloud-snap). For example:

```
$ snap set nextcloud ports.http=81 ports.https=444
```

Original answer below:

I'm afraid this isn't currently possible. However, snapd will soon be introducing some features enabling such snaps to be configured in a standard way. Still a little ways out, but soon you'll be able to do something like the following:

```
$ snap set nextcloud listen=127.0.0.1 http-port=12345
```

It's also worth pointing out that HTTPS is very high on the desired feature list for the Nextcloud snap, and it'll be added soon. Is that all you're wanting, or would you still want to place it behind a proxy?

Comment: I want to be able to put multiple services on the same machine, and as it's just a home server I don't have time to learn how to set it all up, maintain it, and keep it professionally secure, hence why the docker/snap "appliance" appeals.

Comment: Come to think of it, a "let's encrypt" snap that can be easily configured to proxy N other snaps would be cool!

Comment: Ah, yeah okay thanks for explaining your use-case. Indeed, a "let's encrypt" proxy snap is a good idea, as soon as that config capability is in place to tell it what to do.

Comment: Thank's. What does "a little ways out" mean, BTW? Months or years?